# iOS - Will the app store reject an app that records the screen outside of the app and displays the camera in PIP mode at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, review, picture-in-picture

I'm working on an app that allows users to record videos and post them in the app.
Currently, I've got a new feature to develop.
I need to provide the ability for the user can minimize the camera output view in to picture in picture and start to record his screen (to combine this video with previous in one).

It will look like:

1. User is recording a video
2. User pressed the minimize button
3. Camera output screen minimized in to picture in picture
4. User shows all that he wanted to show on his phone (abroad the app)
5. User opened camera output view in full size or finished record

I've made some research on Appstore and checked up to 10 top applications which I found on "Screen recorder" request, and all of them hadn't had this functionality. Instead, all of them suggested overlaying the face cam view to an already recorded video.

And this got me thinking: Perhaps this violates some Apple rules, and such functionality can't be approved on app store review

And this is my question. Thanks

Comment: Questions about what Apple will or won't approve are opinion-based. Only Apple can answer

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because developer-centric questions about application stores are considered off-topic here on SO as discussed in [this meta Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272166/4667835).